# Malloc and alignment

Tags: c, malloc, memory-alignment

As far as I know, every type - like int - can only be stored at memory addresses which start at a power of 2. Now my question is, how can malloc cope with this requirement? For instance, if I call

```
void * ptr;
ptr = malloc(8);
```

Then it is not obvious what I want to store in the given memory block of eight bytes. Is it therefore true that malloc always returns a starting address of the block which is located the largest power of 2 such that every standard type could be stored? If I misunderstand something, please feel free to correct me.

Comment: It's the alignment which is usually a power of 2, not the address.

Comment: ah, ok. thanks. But then still a malloc call does not know about what I want to store in the block and would have to ensure the alignment requirement without knowing what I will eventually store in the block.

Comment: "such that every standard type could be stored?" Yes. It will assume maximum alignment. Likely 4 or 8 bytes for most systems.

Comment: These functions have something called "fundamental alignment requirement", which is supposedly something suiting the specific system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C 2018 7.22.3 specifies the behavior of the memory allocation routines and its paragraph 1 says “… The pointer returned if the allocation succeeds is suitably aligned so that it may be assigned to a pointer to any type of object with a fundamental alignment requirement…”

6.2.8 2 says:

> … The alignment requirements of the following types shall be fundamental alignments:
>
> - all atomic, qualified or unqualified basic types;
> - all atomic, qualified or unqualified enumerated types;
> - all atomic, qualified or unqualified pointer types;
> - all array types whose element type has a fundamental alignment requirement;
> - all types specified in Clause 7 as complete object types;
> - all structure or union types all of whose elements have types with fundamental alignment requirements and none of whose elements have an alignment specifier specifying an alignment that is not a fundamental alignment.

6.2.5 14 says:

> The type `char`, the signed and unsigned integer types, and the floating types are collectively called the *basic types*.

Comment: The rest of the sentence seems quite relevant too: "...and then used to access such an object or an array of such objects in the space allocated", particularly the array part.

Comment: @Lundin: That part is not about alignment. The question is about alignment.

Comment: How exactly is "access an array of objects" not related to alignment?

Comment: @Lundin: “access an array of objects” says nothing about what the alignment of the memory is. It is saying the semantics of reading or writing an object is defined, not where the object is located. That the elements of the array are aligned as required for their type follows mathematically from the fact the starting address is aligned as required and the fact that any array element’s size must be a multple of its alignment requirement (from other parts of the standard).

Comment: It may not be obvious that a type with alignment less than the "fundamental" such as a `uint16_t` is allocated as a contiguous array and not as 2 bytes + padding. Which may otherwise be the case when dealing with an array of struct objects.

Comment: @Lundin: Array elements are contiguously allocated per C 2018 6.2.5 20.

Comment: But what's returned from malloc is not an array, it has no effective type. Thus normative text is required to explain that one may treat it as an array still.

Comment: @Lundin: Whether one may use the space as an array or not is not an alignment issue. The question asks about alignment.

Answer (score 2):

From `man`:

> The malloc() and calloc() functions return a pointer to the allocated memory, which is suitably aligned  for
> any  built-in  type.

So it will be aligned. I also want to add that you're mistaken that:

> As far as I know, every type - like int - can only be stored at memory addresses which start at a power of 2.

Code below works fine on x86_64, but it will not work on ARM.

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main() {
    int a[3];
    a[0] = a[1] = a[2] = 0;
    int *b = 1 + (void *)&a[1];
    *b = 6;
    printf("%x %x %x", a[0], a[1], a[2]);
}
```

As you can see, the pointer is not aligned to 4 bytes, but it will work.

Comment: Note that the C standard says you cannot do arithmetic on a pointer to `void`.  The line `int *b = 1 + (void *)&a[1];` is not strictly allowed.  GCC does allow arithmetic on `void*` values, treating them as equivalent to `char *`.

Comment: @Nierusek, On my x86_64 machine, I receive compiler warning "warning: pointer of type 'void *' used in arithmetic [-Wpointer-arith]".  What compiler and warning level are you using?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I've used `gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1` with flags `-Wall` and `-Wextra`. After I added `-Wpointer-arith` it did show me a warning. I forgot that arithmetic on `void *` is GCC extension.